# Named anonymous functions vs anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

So I am confused as to when I would use an anonymous function such as:

```
let foo = function () {
  //code
}
```

versus a named anonymous function such as:

```
let foo = function foo () {
  //code
}
```

Besides browser support, namely IE, are there any differences between the two? When should I use one over the other?

Comment: Neither of them are anonymous. In both cases `foo.name` is `foo`

Comment: use a name to self-refer to it within the function, since you can't use `arguments.callee` in `use strict`

Comment: The second function is not anonymous since you just gave it a name.

Comment: @gurvinder372 the first function is anonymous and assigned to a variable. The second is also assigned, but it's named.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Then how come they have same name property value?

Comment: @gurvinder372 in the first example, you're seeing the variable name. Try `let bar = function() { ... }` and compare with `let bar = function foo() { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, where the function declaration name is the same as the variable it is assigned to, it doesn't make much difference.

If you used a different name for the definition and assignment, the name on the right takes precedence in naming the function:

```
foo = function bar() {}
foo.name  // "bar"
```

In both cases you assign your function to a variable (function expression), but in the first case you assign an unnamed/anonymous function, whereas in the second case you assign a named function. When assigning an anonymous function to a variable in such a simple expression, the JS engine is able to name the function properly.

Consider the following case where this assignment is non-obvious for the engine:

```
function p(fun) { return fun; }
foo = p(function() {})
foo.name  // empty string
```

TL;DR; with named functions you often get better stack traces.