# JavaScript Function with 2 names?

Tags: javascript, function

I know this might be a simple question, but I'm learning JavaScript and found these two ways to define functions:

#### Method 1

```js
var myFunction = function() {
    statements
}
```

#### Method 2

```js
var myFunction = function namedFunction(){
    statements
}
```

My question is: what is the difference between the name of the variable and the name of the function?
Could I call the second function with myFunction(); and namedFunction(); ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `myFunction` is a *variable* pointing at a *function* named `namedFunction`

Comment: Duplicate of [Named anonymous functions vs anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515483/named-anonymous-functions-vs-anonymous-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that the `namedFunction` becomes an identifier inside the second function, to refer to the function without having to use the outer `myFunction` variable name:

```js
var myFunction = function namedFunction(){
    console.log('running');
    setTimeout(namedFunction, 1000);
};

myFunction();
```

It's not particularly useful here, since you *could* just refer to the outer variable, but it becomes more useful when there *isn't* an outer variable you can cleanly reference, eg:

```js
const obj = {
  nested: {
    fn: function namedFunction(){
      console.log('running');
      setTimeout(namedFunction, 1000);
      // the above looks cleaner than
      // setTimeout(obj.nested.fn, 1000);
    }
  }
};

obj.nested.fn();
```

> Could I call the second function with myFunction(); and namedFunction(); ?

Yes, both will refer to the function, though the `namedFunction` identifier will be scoped only inside the function, whereas the `myFunction` identifier will be scoped anywhere in the outer script.